# Use filtered historical simulation to calculate VaR on a repo trade

Tags: value-at-risk, garch, simulations

I would like to calculate the VaR for a repo trade using filtered historical simulation incorporating GARCH.
So, for example, in the first leg, 3000 of bond goes out on day 1. In the second leg, 3000 of bond is repurchased, occuring in 12 months time.Between day1 and day250 (12 months), the conditional volatility forecast by GARCH would change.

Could I use a filtered historical simulation for both legs and then calculate a total VaR result? That is, generate a forecast daily return series for each leg using GARCH and calculated standardised residuals, combine the final forecast distributions for both legs (whcih each would be from 30,000 paths each) and take a quantile result as VaR for the trade?

I did think to just use the forecast volatility generated from the GARCH processes for both legs in the variance operator formula, but that assumes joint normal distribution that I wanted to avoid.
Thanks in advance all